# DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'

Tags: android, android-databinding

Gets following warning when building the project

```
DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'.
```

I am using `Android Studio Canary 6`

Answer (score 379, accepted):

Starting from `Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0-alpha05` there is a new block called `buildFeatures` to enable build features.

So in order to enable databinding with new AGP plugin you have do like following in module (ex: app) level gradle file

**build.gradle ( Groovy DSL )**

```
// shorter version
// android.buildFeatures.dataBinding true


// longer version

android {

    buildFeatures {

         dataBinding true

         // for view binding:
         // viewBinding true
    }
}
```

**build.gradle.kts ( Kotlin DSL )**

```
// shorter version
// android.buildFeatures.dataBinding = true


// longer version

android {

  buildFeatures {

         dataBinding = true

         // for view binding:
         // viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#buildFeatures

Comment: what worked for me is 
        buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
       }

Comment: In order to get rid of build warnings you will also need to remove the old "dataBinding { enabled = true }" block.

Answer (score 49):

Put it in build.gradle(app level).It will work with android studio version greater than or equal to 4.0.0.

```
android {
    buildFeatures{ 
        dataBinding true // for data binding 
        viewBinding true // for view binding
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39):

This warning occurs because

```
    dataBinding {
        enabled=true
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled=true
    }
```

This code style is deprecated and it will remove from the gradle version 5
now if you still want to use this then you can use androidx legacy support dependencies

in app lavel build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

otherwise you can use new code style to enable data binding and view binding

like this

```
android {

  buildFeatures {

         dataBinding = true

         // for view binding:
         // viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> Put this code in  **Gradle Scripts >> build.gradle(Module: appName.app)**

after the **buildTypes**, include the data biding code

```
buildTypes {
       release {
           .......
          ........
       }
   }
 //here is the code...
   buildFeatures {
       dataBinding = true
   }
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for the new feature `viewBinding`, try this for `Groovy`

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

and this for `Kotlin`

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

But, to use the default android data binding

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

also, be aware to use

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:4.0.0"
```

Answer (score 4):

1- add dataBinding under buildFeatures like this:

```
android {
...
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
...
}
```

2- Change dagger version to 2.31.2:

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
```

3- Change also butterKnife version to 10.2.3:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
buildFeatures {

        //just for dataBinding ，It has nothing to do with viewBinding 
        dataBinding = true

        //just for viewBinding ，It has nothing to do with dataBinding
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

Look at the notes above，so it should be very clear

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.poet.navviewmodeljave"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    //dataBinding.enabled true
    buildFeatures.dataBinding
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add buildFeatures in your gradle module

```
android {
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

example:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```