# This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, developer-tools

**Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException'.**

*spent much time for this error but I don't get it , what's wrong with my code in android studio , when  I  run  app*

**Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException**

Comment: You are using a gradle plugin developed for Java 8 but your used Java version is higher. The java.xml.bind package was disabled in Java9+10 and removed in Java11. The easiest was would be to switch the project to a Java 8 JDK in project settings.

Comment: sounds good , but how to  switch from 11 to 8 Java in Android studio thanks ?

Comment: did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 46):

I too faced the same issue when I updated my Android Studio to V4.2. I had to modify two files.

In build.gradle, I changed dependency
from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties, I changed the distributionUrl
from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

to

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Comment: I just change to   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'  for as4.2 , it works thanks.

Comment: Another solution by @Dheeraj Sharma was changing the classpath gradle to 4.2.2 and the distribution url version to gradle-6.7.1-all.zip.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing the Android JDK path by JDK 8.

First you need to download and install **JDK 8** from this link
[JDK 8] (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

and should change your JDK path manually:
Go to **Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location -> select the three dots button -> select the JDK 8 folder** installed in your pc (generally it will be in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.. ) press ok. it solved this problem for me.

Comment: You are the real life-saver! THIS should be the accepted answer since updating gradle and AGP isn't always the way to go for some projects...

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this issue and this helped me to rectify.
In `build.grade`, change the **classpath** to

```
classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties, change the distributionUrl

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because your Android Studio was upgraded to 4.2, and in 4.2 the AS is build in java 11, you should change your JDK path manually,
Project Structure -> SDK Location, don't use your Android Studio.app's JDK path. install or change another one.

Comment: Hi Smith, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by updating "DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'"

```
android {

    buildFeatures {

         dataBinding true

         // for view binding:
         // viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Reference
[DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390492/dsl-element-android-databinding-enabled-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with)

Answer (score 0):

I simply upgraded Gradle and it worked